# Create a dynamic nested object from array of properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This sounds like a simple task, but I can't quite figure it out: I have an array :

```
var array = ['opt1','sub1','subsub1','subsubsub1']
```

From that I want to generate the following objects:

```
{
  opt1:{
    sub1:{
      subsub1:{
        subsubsub1:{}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a way to do it, making a string and using eval, but I'm looking to avoid that, any idea?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var array = ['opt1','sub1','subsub1','subsubsub1'];
var object = {};
array.reduce(function(o, s) { return o[s] = {}; }, object);
console.log(object);
```

But this was only introduced in ECMAScript 5.1, so it won't be supported in some older browsers. If you want something that will be supported by legacy browsers, you could use the polyfill technique described in the MDN article above, or a simple `for`-loop, like this:

```js
var array = ['opt1','sub1','subsub1','subsubsub1'];
var object = {}, o = object;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    o = o[array[i]] = {};
}
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Or consider `.reduceRight()` so that the return value is the top-level object.

Comment: For me both are not working at all...try console...?!

Comment: @Beat I've converted the code blocks to snippets so you can see them in action. If you're still having issues, try to put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or ask a question with a snippet that demonstrates what's not working -- feel free to reference this answer in your question for clarification.

Comment: Allright. I was using the returning object from reduce function rather than `object` itself. But your edit makes it more clearer now!

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) to transform the array into a 'chain' of objects:

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const object = array.reduceRight((obj, next) => ({[next]: obj}), {});

// Example:
console.log(object); // {"a":{"b":{"c":{}}}}
```

Answer (score 7):

you could use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#set) set function

```
_.set(yourObject, 'a.b.c')
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use the following Function

```
function arr2nestedObject(myArray){
 var cp_myArray = myArray;
 var lastobj = {};
 while(cp_myArray.length>0){
    newobj = {};
    var prop = cp_myArray.pop();
    newobj[prop] = lastobj;
    lastobj = newobj;
 }
 return lastobj;
}
```

The following code:

```
var myArray = ["personal-information", "address", "street",'Great-Success'];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2nestedObject(myArray),undefined,2));
```

Would Produce the Following Output:

```
{
  "personal-information": {
   "address": {
    "street": {
     "Great-Success": {}
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if that was what you meant.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As @p.s.w.g answer is a very good answer with pure js, but if you want an alternative with in a  descriptive and functional way of that and `set a value for final nested prop`, you can use `ramdajs assocPath` https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assocPath like below:

```
var array = ['opt1','sub1','subsub1','subsubsub1'];

R.assocPath(array, "the value", {});
```

[image]

**more details:**

> Makes a shallow clone of an object, setting or overriding the nodes
> required to create the given path, and placing the specific value at
> the tail end of that path. Note that this copies and flattens
> prototype properties onto the new object as well. All non-primitive
> properties are copied by reference.

examples:

```
R.assocPath(['a', 'b', 'c'], 42, {a: {b: {c: 0}}}); //=> {a: {b: {c: 42}}}

// Any missing or non-object keys in path will be overridden
R.assocPath(['a', 'b', 'c'], 42, {a: 5}); //=> {a: {b: {c: 42}}}
```